# Работа с require_once; взятие содержимого в переменную

Tags: php, require

Маститые разработчики одного из проектов используют [в своём примере](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-oauthclient-php/blob/master/demo/index.php) нижеследующий код.

```
<php
$configFile = __DIR__ . '/config.php';
$config = require_once($configFile);
echo $config['url'];
?>
```

Содержимое конфига:

```
<php
$url = 'https://example.com';
?>
```

У меня этот код не выдаёт ничего. Пусто. Путь к файлу верный. В чём тут может быть подвох?

Comment: для того, чтобы переменной что-то присвоилось, файл должен что-то возвращать (`return`). Да и не сказал бы я, что код там очень уж хороший

Comment: Содержимое конфига,  в вашем случае,  должно быть таким: ```<?php return array("url" => "https://example.com");```